# Получить записи за последние 3 месяца на основе поля таблицы

Tags: oracle, дата, plsql

Есть таблица table1:

```
| code | pay_date    | pay_sum |
+------+-------------+---------+
| 134  | 10.09.2021  | 13000   |
| 134  | 11.08.2021  | 11500   |
| 134  | 02.05.2021  | 10500   |
| 134  | 08.01.2021  | 13100   |
| 134  | 02.12.2020  | 13050   |
| 134  | 19.11.2020  | 13008   |
```

Как получить записи за последние 3 месяца на основе поля таблицы?
Ожидаю получить :

```
 | code | pay_date    | pay_sum |
 +------+-------------+---------+
 | 134  | 10.09.2021  | 13000   |
 | 134  | 11.08.2021  | 11500   |
```

Comment: Получить макс. дату в подзапросе и плясать от неё.

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно использовать окно по диапазону (RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND ...)

```
WITH source_data AS
(SELECT 130 + LEVEL AS f_id
       ,ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('10.05.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), LEVEL) AS dat
       ,-3 AS p_shift
   FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3),
your_query AS
 (SELECT s.f_id
        ,s.p_shift
        ,TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(s.dat, LEVEL), 'DD') + LEVEL AS dat
        ,TRUNC(dbms_random.value(1000, 100000)) AS val
    FROM source_data s
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
         AND PRIOR s.f_id = s.f_id
         AND PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL)

SELECT f_id
      ,dat
      ,val
--,shift_dat
--,cnt_days
--,range_dat
--,max_dat
  FROM (SELECT g.*
              ,MAX(g.shift_dat) OVER(PARTITION BY g.f_id) AS max_dat
          FROM (SELECT f.*
                  FROM (SELECT q.f_id
                              ,q.dat
                              ,q.val
                              , -- Находим дату из выборки по условию сдвига от текущей
                               MIN(q.dat) OVER(PARTITION BY q.f_id ORDER BY q.dat DESC RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND (q.dat - ADD_MONTHS(q.dat, p_shift)) following) AS shift_dat
                               -- cnt_days и range_dat для наглядности
                              ,q.dat - ADD_MONTHS(q.dat, q.p_shift) AS cnt_days
                              ,q.dat - (q.dat - ADD_MONTHS(q.dat, q.p_shift)) AS range_dat
                          FROM your_query q) f) g)
 WHERE dat >= max_dat -- Оставляем только данные за N месяцев от последней записи
 ORDER BY f_id
         ,dat DESC
```

Запрос из таблицы

| N | ID | DATE | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 131 | 11.07.2021 | 75883 |
| 2 | 131 | 12.08.2021 | 83774 |
| 3 | 131 | 13.09.2021 | 75185 |
| 4 | 131 | 14.10.2021 | 62011 |
| 5 | 131 | 15.11.2021 | 7717 |
| 6 | 131 | 16.12.2021 | 54486 |
| 7 | 131 | 17.01.2022 | 58391 |
| 8 | 131 | 18.02.2022 | 94468 |
| 9 | 131 | 19.03.2022 | 73036 |
| 10 | 131 | 20.04.2022 | 67840 |
| 11 | 132 | 11.08.2021 | 45329 |
| 12 | 132 | 12.09.2021 | 16189 |
| 13 | 132 | 13.10.2021 | 77150 |
| 14 | 132 | 14.11.2021 | 16320 |
| 15 | 132 | 15.12.2021 | 17518 |
| 16 | 132 | 16.01.2022 | 10057 |
| 17 | 132 | 17.02.2022 | 94057 |
| 18 | 132 | 18.03.2022 | 59455 |
| 19 | 132 | 19.04.2022 | 15799 |
| 20 | 132 | 20.05.2022 | 52519 |
| 21 | 133 | 11.09.2021 | 68274 |
| 22 | 133 | 12.10.2021 | 68247 |
| 23 | 133 | 13.11.2021 | 29625 |
| 24 | 133 | 14.12.2021 | 50319 |
| 25 | 133 | 15.01.2022 | 66399 |
| 26 | 133 | 16.02.2022 | 6745 |
| 27 | 133 | 17.03.2022 | 93009 |
| 28 | 133 | 18.04.2022 | 55717 |
| 29 | 133 | 19.05.2022 | 32515 |
| 30 | 133 | 20.06.2022 | 16717 |

Результат

| N | ID | DATE | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 131 | 20.04.2022 | 16183 |
| 2 | 131 | 19.03.2022 | 73312 |
| 3 | 131 | 18.02.2022 | 74667 |
| 4 | 132 | 20.05.2022 | 14495 |
| 5 | 132 | 19.04.2022 | 90913 |
| 6 | 132 | 18.03.2022 | 56791 |
| 7 | 133 | 20.06.2022 | 89130 |
| 8 | 133 | 19.05.2022 | 50841 |
| 9 | 133 | 18.04.2022 | 74972 |

еще вариант запроса с выбором от какой записи с конца считать

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT g.*
              ,MAX(g.shift_dat) OVER(PARTITION BY g.f_id) AS max_dat
          FROM (SELECT f.*
                  FROM (SELECT q.f_id
                              ,q.dat
                              ,q.val
                              , MIN(q.dat) OVER(PARTITION BY q.f_id ORDER BY q.dat DESC RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND (q.dat - ADD_MONTHS(q.dat, p_shift)) following) AS shift_dat
                              ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY q.f_id ORDER BY q.dat DESC) AS gr                       
                          FROM your_query q) f) g
         WHERE gr >= 3 -- Выбор месяца с конца. Если хотим отобрать за предыдущие p_shift месяцев от N-ой Даты c конца выборки
        )
WHERE dat >= max_dat -- Оставляем только данные за N месяцев от нужной записи
 ORDER BY f_id
         ,dat DESC
```